How to restore my tile pavement?
In my backyard there's a tile-paved area and there's a line where it goes from one level to another level:
https://imgur.com/a/ZYN5Xfy
The problem is, a lot of tiles on that edge are not held in place securely anymore.
On the image above, you can see a layer of old concrete, about 1" thick. I would like to not remove it (to save a lot of time). I want to use a thin layer of some special stone/brick/concrete "glue" instead of concrete/mortar to put the tiles back on it. I don't want to use concrete/mortar, because it will require a thicker layer and my tiles will become higher than the adjacent tiles.
I'm in the US, can you please help me choose the right "glue"?

Looks like you have some kind of paver patio.  Not clear if it's all on concrete base or aggregate, but the "step" at least appears to have a hard setting material.  Anything you put there without removing the existing mortar will add at least a little bit of height to the step.  You could try a paver adhesive, with the understanding that you may have to come back at a later date and chip out the existing mortar to use a more traditional method.

Thank you @Huesman. The patio is not on concrete base, but the step is on stones. I started removing 2-3 mm for a paver adhesive with a belt sander & angle grinder, but it was so taking so much time and belts/disks, that I decided to try to my hammer drill to remove the old concrete. In 10 minutes I removed all of it :) So I will go on with good old concrete now :)

I hope you're going to use mortar and not concrete!

hi, a HomeDepot worker recommended me this:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-60-lb-Sand-Mix-65306217/100350697
Is it fine?
